# LINQ to CRM or just LINQ to SQL/Entity

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm

I've used LINQ on the fetched entities from CRM Dynamics but despite the original source of the data, it was still only operating via LINQ to data structure. Now, I've got a hint that there exists possibility to use LINQ to query the DB in Dynamics directly, which was surprising but (under assumption that it works out) fantastic.

So, I've checked the SDK and samples and as far I've could see, there is some kind of LINQ to CRM thing going on there. Since I have hard time believing that Microsoft has spent so much development hours on such a specialized product, I'm suspecting that it's in fact LINQ to SQL/Entity run under the CRM (Dynamics is powered by MS SQL Server, isn't it?) and I'd like someone to either deny or confirm it.

For instance I've seen those two articles: [document #1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx) and [document #2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334504.aspx).

EDIT:

My question is, hence, if there is a true LINQ-to-CRM or if we're dealing with LINQ-to-SQL (or something similar) run under the real of CRM Dynamics.

Comment: Johnsson  Can you please look over your question.  It is very difficult to determine what you are asking.

Comment: @DavidBasarab I've tried. See if it's clearer.

Comment: @AndreasJohansson: Why is this distinction important?

Comment: @PeterMajeed Pure, academic curiosity (as far I'm regarded). Besides that I can imagine there **might** be a difference in e.g. performance speed. Having said that, I was only curious for the sake of knowing that. Call it an ice breaking conversation opener at a party (if the party accommodates nerdy programmers sans skills other than coding, hehe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples you cited appear to be using LINQ-to-Objects.

From [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328028.aspx), it seems Microsoft *has* created a specialized API for CRM, in the form of `OrganizationServiceContext`.

This class is for accessing a SOAP endpoint, so it's **not** leveraging L2S or LINQ-to-EF.

> In Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online, you
>   can use .NET Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) to write queries. You
>   can *use the OrganizationServiceContext class or a deriving class
>   created by the CrmSvcUtil tool to write LINQ queries that access the
>   SOAP endpoint* (Organization.svc). The OrganizationServiceContext class
>   contains an underlying LINQ query provider that translates LINQ
>   queries from Microsoft Visual C# or Microsoft Visual Basic .NET syntax
>   into the query API used by Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

Whether or not the CRM web-service uses LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-EF against SQL Server is a different question.

Comment: By pure academic curiosity - how could one get to know if it's the case whether LINQ2CRM is powered by LINQ2anythingElse or a "real" thing?

Comment: An easier check would be to see if the types you are querying over derive from IEnumerable<T> or IQueryable<T>, or have native Where, Select, OrderBy, etc. methods. If it's just IEnumerable, then you're just dealing with LINQ to Objects. Otherwise, use ILSpy/Reflector to check the GetEnumerator method from your IQueryable source.